# Does SharePoint 2010 work with Firefox?

Tags: 2010, browser-compatibility, prerequisites

In SharePoint 2007, it was impossible to work as a site administrator or farm administrator, when using Firefox as a web browser.

Does SharePoint 2010 work with any web browser (or at least Chrome / firefox / opera) or is it still a IE-only application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firefox will work in most scenarios. However, at some points, SharePoint is still using ActiveX components, so Firefox won't work there.

For instance: the Datasheet View option for a list in the ribbon will be disabled.
Also, Explorer View for a document library will be disabled.

In short: most limitations come from the use of ActiveX components, the reason why you get the same limitations for Internet Explorer 64-bit, 'cause the ActiveX components are 32-bits...

I also ran into problems with opening Excel documents: 
http://itblog.wolthaus.net/2011/08/sharepoint-2010-doesnt-play-nice-with-64-bit-internet-explorer/

Comment: Another major disappointment is that when you have any list (custom list or calendar or task list), and if any of those fields are configured as a Rich Text field, Firefox and Chrome will not display the HTML toolbar. You can edit Wikis and the ribbon toolbar works but Rich Text fields in lists are not support with non-IE browsers.

Comment: IMO, this is one of the most compelling reasons to move to 2013 as these are all supported for FireFox and Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

I've used FireFox and Chrome to do most everything in SharePoint 2010. I have not run into any major issues.

According to this article SP2010 has two support levels "Supported" "Supported with Limitations"

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes, SharePoint 2010 supports Firefox and Safari. For more information see Technet: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For FBA enabled sites Logout is always issue for Chrome and Mozilla .
Please find the link : [Logout in Mozilla and chrome not working / ADFS Authentication](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/35251/logout-in-mozilla-and-chrome-not-working-adfs-authentication)

Comment: Hi Nikhil, your answer has been flagged due to lack of details. Can you please elaborate a bit?