# Logout in Mozilla and chrome not working / ADFS Authentication

Tags: 2010, application-pages, browser-compatibility

I have custom logout page created.
I have used an application page for logout. In the application page, I use a javascript and say `document.execCommand(ClearAuthenticationCache)`.

This works fine in IE to logout, but when I try to logout in Mozilla or Chrome, I am unable to logout.  Please provide me details on how to succesfully logout in a custom application page in Mozilla and Chrome. I am using ADFS authentication.

Answer (score 1):

If the user logs out in IE, he will be having `document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache");`
else if user logs out from Mozilla, he will be sent to ADFS logout page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function _spBodyOnLoad() {
        var PreviousPage = document.referrer.split('/')[3];      
        if (PreviousPage == "adfs") {
            var searchString = getQueryStringParameter('site');
            PreviousPage=searchString;
            }
        var browserName = navigator.appName.toLowerCase();
        if (browserName.indexOf("internet explorer") != -1) {
            document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache");
            location.replace("/ABCD/SitePages/Page.aspx?site=" + PreviousPage);
            }
            else {
                var LogOutUrl = "https://ABCD/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignout1.0";
                location.replace(LogOutUrl);         
        }          
    } 

    function getQueryStringParameter(paramName) { 
        var searchString = window.location.search.substring(1); 
        var i; 
        var val; 
        var params = searchString.split("&"); 
        for (i = 0; i < params.length; i++) { 
            val = params[i].split("="); 
            if (val[0] == paramName) { 
                return val[1]; 
            } 
        }

        return null; 
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: function getQueryStringParameter(paramName) {
            var searchString = window.location.search.substring(1);
            var i;
            var val;
            var params = searchString.split("&");

            for (i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                val = params[i].split("=");
                if (val[0] == paramName) {
                    return val[1];
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

Answer (score 0):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/sharepointdevelopment/thread/ff30c5dd-356f-48b9-a3b7-72d477d64d14 appears to have a solution.

I do not have a site up that i could test this on, but let me know if it is helpful!

Comment: thanks, but i have tried this . . this doesnt really work.