# Does SharePoint 2013 work with Firefox on Ubuntu?

Tags: 2013, firefox

Does SharePoint 2013 work with Firefox on Ubuntu?

[I found the question about SharePoint 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17884/does-sharepoint-2010-work-with-firefox) interesting, but is SharePoint 2013 worse or better than SharePoint 2010 when it comes to Firefox support on Ubuntu?

[According to this page about browser support it seems that Firefox on windows](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526.aspx) should be ok, but since there is a long list of plugins and since they probably does not exist on Ubuntu it seems like Firefox on Ubuntu will problematic.

Would someone like to clarify the situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work, but it is not officially supported.You should make sure that you're using a not so legacy version of Firefox (anything >= 4 will be mostly ok)

SharePoint 2013's html is much **cleaner** and heavily rely on recent **web standards** (html5, css 3, JS) so having a good browser is mandatory to ensure the best experience.

A few component might not work as expected or at all (eg: the data sheet view, the online presence icon, etc.) but it's pretty similar to running Chrome or FF in Windows or even running IE in 64bit mode.

You need to check with the chart at the bottom if you won't be lacking a native functionality if you don't have the activeX installed but if you're doing regular collaboration work / publishing / document management you won't have issue.